How to avoid rebasing branches when trying to merge into develop
I've been experiencing a particular problem with git at a new project that I was added to as a collaborator. Here's what I usually do:

Create a new branch from develop in order to fix a bug:

$ git checkout develop && git pull origin develop && git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_1


After making changes, I push them to the repository:

$ git add . && git commit -am 'some-message' && git push origin NEW_BRANCH_1


While I wait for a code review, I create another branch for another bug fix:

$ git checkout develop && git pull origin develop && git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_2


I make and push changes:

$ git add . && git commit -am 'another-message' && git push origin NEW_BRANCH_2

At the moment, it's only me creating PRs.
Now onto the problem. After receiving successful code reviews, I first merge NEW_BRANCH_1 into develop with the fast-forward algorithm. After a successful merge, I then subsequently try to merge NEW_BRANCH_2 into develop, but then am faced with the following error:

The merge could not be completed because the repository is configured to require fast-forward merges and the target branch contains commits which are not present in the source branch. To perform this merge, either merge develop into NEW_BRANCH_2, or rebase NEW_BRANCH_2 onto develop

With this, I'm forced to select the option rebase and fast-forward.
How can I avoid this? I kind of understand that NEW_BRANCH_2 doesn't have the commit from NEW_BRANCH_1, but there's got to be some approach to this that'll avoid rebasing. At any point, I could have up to 10 open PRs, all waiting for a code review, and checking out into each of these bug fix branches and running git pull origin develop --rebase && git push origin <BRANCH_NAME> can become cumbersome.

You have two options if the fast-forward requirement remains: (1) rebase your branch 2 ontop of the new develop. (2) Merge develop into your branch 2; thereafter, your branch 2 will be fast-forward-able.

if you merge the target branch into your branch, a fast-forward would be possible.... but history will be a mess as time goes on.... and backporting will be hell, for example.

Its best practice to pull before you push anyway.  So not a real way around that.  You can make your life easier by setting git pull to always do a --rebase via:
git config --global pull.rebase true

then just git pull  && git push
In general, keep your local up to date with remote often
